# VB.Net Search for files matching REGEX

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hi I have a really basic question that the answer completely escapes me. I want to search in a given directory for a file REGEX match. I've tried all kinds of iterations but nothing is working for me. My REGEX is "*_Ch[0-9]+.sgm" and it should work. My files are named "Bld1_Ch1.sgm" and iterates.

The error I get is "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Test\06-GCS Bursting Script\TO 33D1-8-2-2-2 RAMTS FI\Bld1'.'"

Thank you for your patience and help.
Maxine

```
Private Sub btnImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnImport.Click
    Dim searchDir As String = txtSGMFile.Text & "\" & txtUnique.Text
    Dim searchFolder As String = "\" & txtUnique.Text
    Dim searchPattern = "*_Ch[0-9]+.sgm"

    Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(searchDir, searchPattern)
    For Each file In files
        MsgBox(file)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Try making it `.*` instead of just `*` in the beginning of regex? Also, better to escape the dot and write your regex as `.*_Ch[0-9]+\.sgm`

Comment: I get an illegal character error

Comment: Looks like you might have to escape \ as \\ or can you try this regex `.*_Ch[0-9]+[.]sgm` ?

Comment: When I use [.]sgm I get the following error System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Test\06-GCS Bursting Script\TO 33D1-8-2-2-2 RAMTS FI\Bld1'.'

Comment: The whole reason for your issue is because that method does **not** support regular expressions... Please see the details 
[**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_) and read the "search pattern" section.

Comment: What would I do instead?

Comment: You can still use regex, for example along the lines of: `Dim reg As Regex = New Regex("_Ch[0-9]+.sgm") Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(yourPath).Where(Function(path) reg.IsMatch(path)).ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working use this code! Thank you everyone for your help.

```
    Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.sgm")

    Dim rx = New Regex(".*_Ch\d\.sgm") ' or Dim rx = new Regex(".*_v[0-9]\.pdf")

    For Each file In files
        If rx.IsMatch(file) Then
            ' do something with the file
            MsgBox(file)
        End If
    Next file
```